# antlr grammar ignoring characters which should cause errors

Tags: c#, antlr, grammar, dsl

I'm just getting into antlr grammars and I thought I had a pretty simple one.  The problem I am running into is this [1+2] parses to

- PLUS (+)

  - INT_LITERAL (1)
  - INT_LITERAL (2)

correctly which is good but [a1+2] also parses into

- PLUS (+)

  - INT_LITERAL (1)
  - INT_LITERAL (2)

instead of giving me an error like I would expect.

Thanks in advance.

```
grammar MyExpressions;

options {
    language=CSharp3;
    TokenLabelType=CommonToken;
    ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
    output=AST;
    k=10;
}

@lexer::namespace{Expressions}
@parser::namespace{Expressions}


/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

public root: LBRACKET! expression^ RBRACKET!;
expression: binaryOperation;

binaryOperation: (term PLUS^ term);

term: INT_LITERAL;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

PLUS: '+';
LBRACKET: '[';
RBRACKET: ']';  
INT_LITERAL: '1'..'9'+;
WS: ' ';
```

I fixed the issue by adding this to my grammar:
    @lexer::members {
    public override void DisplayRecognitionError(string[] tokenNames,
                                        RecognitionException e) {
        string hdr = GetErrorHeader(e);
        string msg = GetErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);

```
    throw new SyntaxException(hdr,msg);
    }
}

@parser::members {
    public override void DisplayRecognitionError(string[] tokenNames,
                                        RecognitionException e) {
        string hdr = GetErrorHeader(e);
        string msg = GetErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);

        throw new SyntaxException(hdr,msg);
    }
}
```

SyntaxException is a custom exception that I created for my application.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was going on.  When you use the @members construct it adds the code to the parser but not the lexer.  You have to prefix it like this @lexer::members.  Once I did that lexer generated correctly.

```
public override void DisplayRecognitionError(string[] tokenNames,
                                    RecognitionException e) {
    string hdr = GetErrorHeader(e);
    string msg = GetErrorMessage(e, tokenNames);
    // Now do something with hdr and msg...

    System.Console.WriteLine("Header:  " + hdr);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Message: " + msg);

    throw new System.Exception("Syntax Error: " + hdr + " " + msg);
}
```

I'm still a little thrown off because the NumberOfSyntaxErrors count still showed 0, but the grammar is no breaking like it should.

Comment: Could it be you are mixing concept of lexer and parser? You didn't define any rule for fallback when scanning -- i.e. what should happen when the characters don't match any of the valid rules? I don't know what ANTLR does in such case, but I guess this is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

'a'  is an invalid character and so you should've gotten a tokenization error. The parser will not see it.
Ter

Comment: I'm new to the whole antlr thing and DSl creation in general.  Where would I see the tokenizer error?

Comment: I looked at the NumberOfSyntaxErrors property on both the lexer and the parser and it had 0 for both.  I also overloaded the DisplayRecognitionError method but I didn't get any results from it.